# 45 Degree anti clockwise rotation with respect to the center of a 5 × 5 2D Array

Tags: java, c++, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

**Rotate the array 45 degree anti-clock wise like this:**

Example:
**input**

```
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 1
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
```

**Output**

```
1 0 0 0 1
0 1 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 1 0
1 0 0 0 1
```

**Another example:
input**

```
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
```

**output**

```
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Choose **one** language. And show a [example] of what you've tried and explain what problems you're having with it.

Comment: I would rotate the shells separately. The center doesn't move. In the first shell, each element moves one place. In the second shell, each element moves two places.

Answer (score 1):

Each index in the input array maps to an index in the output array. There is a slight pattern to this mapping, so it would be possible to develop a more elegant algorithm, but the easiest way to do it would be the brute force method:

```
arrOutput[0][2] = arr[0][0];
arrOutput[0][3] = arr[0][1];
arrOutput[0][4] = arr[0][2];
arrOutput[1][4] = arr[0][3];
arrOutput[2][4] = arr[0][4];


arrOutput[0][1] = arr[1][0];
arrOutput[1][2] = arr[1][1];
arrOutput[1][3] = arr[1][2];
arrOutput[2][3] = arr[1][3];
arrOutput[3][4] = arr[1][4];


arrOutput[0][0] = arr[2][0];
arrOutput[1][1] = arr[2][1];
arrOutput[2][2] = arr[2][2];
arrOutput[3][3] = arr[2][3];
arrOutput[4][4] = arr[2][4];


arrOutput[1][0] = arr[3][0];
arrOutput[2][1] = arr[3][1];
arrOutput[3][1] = arr[3][2];
arrOutput[3][2] = arr[3][3];
arrOutput[4][3] = arr[3][4];


arrOutput[2][0] = arr[4][0];
arrOutput[3][0] = arr[4][1];
arrOutput[4][0] = arr[4][2];
arrOutput[4][1] = arr[4][3];
arrOutput[4][2] = arr[4][4];
```

This will rotate it 45 degrees counter-clockwise. If you swap the left indices and the right indices you can rotate it 45 degrees clockwise.

Comment: There must be a certain algorithm